# Need help creating a python loop

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and need help making my email sender a loop. I want the code to loop so that I can enter multiple emails while bypassing the email password (after the first execution).

Here is my code:

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage
port = 465
password = input('Type your password and press enter: ')
sender = 'email@gmail.com'
receiver = input('Enter the email you wish to receive the message and press enter: ')

subject = "Thank you!"
body = """
asdfgh

"""

em = EmailMessage()
em['From'] = sender
em['To'] = receiver
em['Subject'] = subject
em.set_content(body)

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender, password)
    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, em.as_string())

print('Email sent!')
```

I do not know where to start. I only know the very basics of the for loop.

Comment: Have you tried a Python tutorial? You may also want to check [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example of how you could input strings in a loop:

```
receivers = []
while not receivers or receivers[-1]:
    receivers.append(input(
        'Enter the email you wish to receive the message and press enter: '
    ))
receivers.pop()
```

This `while` loop will continue *while* the list is empty (`not receivers`) *or* the last element of the list (`receivers[-1]`) is *not* empty.  That means that it will keep prompting you for input until you enter an empty string.

After the loop is done, `receivers.pop()` will pop off the last element of the list (the empty string you entered to terminate the loop).

Once you have the list, you might want to turn it into a single string using `str.join`, e.g.:

```
em['To'] = ','.join(receivers)
```